# How to update existing itemCode

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code

```
bindingSource1.CurrencyManager.AddNew();
int dtCode = dsData1.Item.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.DataCode == txtItem.Text).Count();
            
if (dtCode == 0)
{
     DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)bindingSource1.CurrencyManager.Current;
     dr["DataCode"] = txtItem.Text;
     dr["Quantity"] = dtQuantity+1;
}
else
{
     //insert code for update
}
bindingSource1.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit();
```

Can someone know how to do it, instead of this

[image]

My idea is only the highlighted row only shown and when ever itry to enter another item code "axe", quantity +1

Comment: You use `bindingSource1.CurrencyManager.AddNew();` this will always add a new item. The only way to avoid duplicates is to first remove the previous one `bindingSource1.CurrencyManager.RemoveAt(index_to__remove);`, or to recreate the DataTable.

Comment: can you retype my code? @sorifiend

Comment: You have not given enough code for us to fully know what you are doing. Once we see that then there is probably a much cleaner and better solution. Edit your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The solution is probably as simple as editing the contents of the `dsData1` and changing quantity value.

Answer (score 0):

Discover this code

```
DataRow rv = (from fr in dsData1.Item.AsEnumerable()
            where fr.Field<string>("DataCode") == txtItem.Text
        select fr).FirstOrDefault();

if (rv != null)
{
    rv["Quantity"] = Convert.ToDecimal(rv["Quantity"]) + 1;
}
else
{
    bindingSource1.CurrencyManager.AddNew();
    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)bindingSource1.CurrencyManager.Current;
    dr["DataCode"] = txtItem.Text;
    dr["Quantity"] = 1;
    bindingSource1.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit();
}
```